# How does 'The Stack' work?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I cast [Tormented Thoughts](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Tormented%20Thoughts) on my 3/1 creature and to counter my opponent uses [Disperse](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Disperse) to return it to my hand, is my Tormented Thoughts wasted?

Comment: You don't cast Tormented thoughts on a creature. You cast in on a player.

Answer (score 3):

The stack does not matter here. Sacrificing a creature is part of the cost of casting Tormented Thoughts (it says so on the card). By the time your opponent has a chance to cast a spell, the creature you sacrificed will be in your graveyard, and therefore not a legal target for Disperse.

Answer (score 2):

You opponent can't interact with the creature because by the time he/she gains priority to cast Disperse, the creature is in the graveyard.

The process of casting Tormented Thoughts is:

1. Place the card on the stack
2. Announce modes (N/A)
3. Choose targets
4. Choose divisions (N/A)
5. Check targets
6. Calculate cost
7. Pay cost

After 7, players can regain priority.